# New Hardwood Floors Chipping

Tags: wood, flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, hardwood

I just bought a newly built house in Maryland and have been living in it for about three months. Most of the house has hardwood flooring that for the most part looks really good. However, I've found some spots here and there throughout the house that are starting the chip.

What are my least invasive options for fixing this problem? I say least invasive because I do not want to tear up the whole peg board and replace it. I'm thinking that I could put down some wood glue and try to stain that small piece or something; If that's the solution can anyone recommend the materials I need to do that or brands of glue, etc. Or is that a bad idea? I don't want my repair job to be noticeable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the humidity level, and what's the ambient climate where you live? It may be that the boards are too dry and chip at the least amount of pressure.

Comment: I live in Maryland so it's not a dry area. I moved in at the start of November though so I guess it's been dry during the Winter season. Should I be putting a wax down or something?

Comment: The word you're looking for is invasive. "The least invasive option" would imply the most direct option - which leads me to conclude you're not afraid of tearing things up.

Comment: @Vlad no, that is not what "the least invasive option" means... But thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: Hah - had a typo in pointing out your typo. "The least evasive option" would imply the above.

Comment: @VladK it's Sunday :)

Comment: Since it is only a few months old I would call the contractor. The few hardwood floors I have put down continue to dry out for a while and need additional oil. If this is A oil finish I cannot quite tell.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Ed Beal, start a warranty claim in case you start finding it all over. Otherwise yes, if you can lift the feather/chip & work some glue in there that would be great. Immediately wipe up any glue that squeezes out when pressure is applied.

Make sure you put a piece of Saran wrap over it to then clamp it down with something heavy. The Saran wrap ensures you won't glue your heavy item to the floor.

Assuming that works & it seems nice & solid, then you'll need to put at least 3 coats of clear polyurethane over it to avoid Foot, Mop or Swiffer injuries in the future.

Comment: The builder ignores me. I had a problem with my deck wobbling and when I went to closing he said they'd be out the next day to fix it but they never came. I emailed them and they never responded.

Comment: It figures, typical & surprise-surprise! I hate most Contractors & especially Builders. Unfortunately, they're still needed occasionally. Definitely call your local Building, Zoning, Permit or Licensing (whatever yours is called) & see if they have any power in getting the builder to respond. A wobbly deck is a life-safety issue & I know they'll get the builder on that. You shouldn't have to go to Court to reach someone who allegedly takes pride in their work. But, we all know "pride" to them is just another term for Money.

Comment: Yeah I ended up having to take care of the deck myself by calling a ton of people in the county and eventually the senior inspector came out and assured me that it's built to code despite the movement. But yeah good idea, I'll try to contact them and if they don't respond I'll call the county I guess. He's actually building two more houses right down the road from me so I see him out there all the time. Never met him though. At closing he signed some papers to allow his realtor to handle it all. I didn't like that honestly. Wanted to meet the guy who built my home. Nice home all in all though.

Comment: That's really a shame & I really hope the few floor issues is all the problems you ever have again with the place. I'm surprised at the Senior Inspector though, he sounds paid-off (yeah, great world of corruption we've all allowed). Built-Right isn't the same as Attached-Right & that's definitely his jurisdiction too. Don't put the Protest Sign up in the yard until the block's filled. Kind of horrible to say, but you don't want to kill your property value. You can also lodge complaints online with Reviewer sites & The BBB, word does get back & he may then change his tune.

Comment: You're very welcome & best of luck with the floor. It should address the problem areas permanently.